# Set proxy settings in Android for a Shared USB Connection

Tags: networking, proxy, android

I'm trying to share my Ethernet connection with my mobile in order to connect my mobile phone to the organization network. I'm connecting and sharing the connection between my computer and my mobile with a USB cable.

Opening a web page in Chrome, I get the proxy connection error.

I can't find how to configure proxy settings (url, username and password) for the USB connection. I have only seen on the internet how to configure proxy settings for a selected Wifi network.

The connection is shared by my computer with Windows 7 Enterprise ed.

Thanks

Comment: You write "configure proxy settings (url, username and password) not only for Wifi networks." <-- What?

Comment: for a usb connection?  Are you using a USB Wireless Adaptor? The USB aspect is irrelevant. If it were an internal wireless adaptor it'd be the same functionality. You're entering the user/pass for the wireless access point part of your "wireless router"..  See if you still have the same proxy problem with a cable. Then you'd know that/if wireless is irrelevant.

Comment: @barlop I am sharing the Ethernet connection in my computer with my mobile phone through a USB cable

Comment: On my smart "phone", the USB cable is for data transfer and charging. Not for network connection. I can tether them together. Getting my computer to use my mobile's internet connection, but that doesn't involve a USB cable.  Out of interest, what phone is it that you have?

Comment: This is explained in this question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable. I've got a Samsung Galaxy device